# Equivalent of an HTML multiple SELECT box in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'd like to create a `ListBox` in wxPython with the same semantics as a multiple `select` box in HTML.  Specifically I'd like the following semantics

- When the user clicks on an entry in the list, all other entries become de-selected and the clicked entry becomes selected.  If the entry was already selected then it stays selected.
- When the user holds down the Ctrl key while clicking on an entry, all other entries stay unchanged, but it toggles whether the clicked entry is selected.
- When the user holds down shift and clicks on an entry, that entry and every entry between it and the last clicked entry become selected.

In Java I get this by using the `JList` class in Swing and setting the selection mode to `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTED`.  I assume that there's a way to do this with the wxPython toolkit, but I can't figure out how to get a `ListBox` or `ListCtrl` or any other class to do this short of doing an enormous amount of event-driven programming myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [wxLB_EXTENDED](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxlistbox.html) list box style. Specify `style = wx.LB_EXTENDED` when you create the `ListBox`.

You can then use the `GetSelections` method to obtain a list of the selected items.